# Files Deleted on Boot-Up

Tags: raspbian

I accidentally reinstalled Raspbian on my Raspberry Pi and it erased all files I had on my desktop. Is there any way to get them back, or do I have to redo everything I had?

Comment: In what way did you reinstall Raspbian? Did you write a new disk image to the SD card, or did you do it from the Pi through some command?

Comment: When the Pi was starting up, I pressed enter on accident and it started the reinstallation.

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't aware that could happen; how did you install the OS in the first place? With NOOBS, or just a Raspbian image from the website?

Comment: I installed it with NOOBS.

Comment: No backup, no mercy ;-) https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/filesystem/backup.md

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately not... unless you made a backup, or saved the files somewhere other than on your SD card, the installation overwrites everything that's on the card.

Looking at it in a positive light though, you've learned a lesson that all of us get "refresher classes" on from time to time.